# How to show the spinner on the oldview instead of a blank page in backbone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

In my application, I get an intermediate blank page during the transitions. And the ajax spinner shows up in that page.

This is how I have included the spinner in my main.js

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
    $.mobile.loading( 'show');
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $.mobile.loading( 'hide');
});
```

And in router I remove the old view and load the new view to get rid of the zombie view problem, by
 oldview.remove() and oldview.unbind().

My question is how can I show the ajax spinner above the old view instead of shwoing it on the blank page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does this relate to `RequireJS? The question does not make it clear at all.

Comment: Its just that I have all these JS libs included in my app

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Sorry, I was a bit off-topic. I was assuming you already have a jQuery Plugin in order to show/hide a loading overlay on top of any DOM element..

So to put in place my solution , you'd need one.

*Note*: As far as I read, you cannot apply the `$.mobile.loading()` on a specific DOM element.

You could use something like [jquery-loadmask](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) for example, and then restyle the CSS to match the `$.mobile.loading` one.

Or personally I use this [simple jQuery function](https://gist.github.com/Pirhoo/3676651) found on github to achieve the same behavior (might be lighter).

### Original

Have you tried:

```
oldview.$el.loading('show');
```

Also `ajaxSend` being a [global Ajax event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) and further more, not being associated with any DOM element but only the `document.body` element, you kind of have no other choice than dealing with the `show/hide` in your View:

```
var OldView = Backbone.View.extend({

    //...

    events: {
        "click .the-button-trigering-the-ajax-call": "onButtonClicked"
    },

    onButtonClicked: function (e) {
        this.$el.loading('show');
    },

    // And you could get rid of it when rendering
    render: function () {

        this.$el.loading('hide');

        //...

        return this;
    }
});
```

Just one solution.